# a href's not working from inside a modal popup NOT BOOTSTRAP, NOT JQUERY

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, modal-dialog, href

The aside element is a modal popup with multiple a href links inside, none of which are working. I can right click and go to the link but clicking on it does nothing. The open modal is triggered by  Javascript. There are no external libraries, plugins etc that could be causing conflict.

What am I missing here?

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");

const card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
card.forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const cardId = card.getAttribute("data-card");

    const modal = document.getElementById(`${cardId}`);

    modal.classList.remove("hidden");
    overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
    const vScrollPos = window.scrollY;
    document.body.style.position = "fixed";
    document.body.style.top = `-${vScrollPos}px`;

    const closeModal = function() {
      modal.classList.add("hidden");
      overlay.classList.add("hidden");
      const scrollY = document.body.style.top;
      document.body.style.position = "";
      document.body.style.top = "";
      window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollY || "0") * -1);
    };

    const modalCloseBtn = modal.querySelector(".close-modal");
    modalCloseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      closeModal();
    });
    overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.key === "Escape" && !modal.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        closeModal();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(100vw - 16rem);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 16rem);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 6rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: all;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 5;
}

.modal-title {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<article class="card" data-card="modal1">
  <img class="card-img" src="img/card-thumb/cardImg.jpg" alt="card image">
  <p class="card-title">open card modal</p>
</article>

<aside class="modal hidden" id="modal1">
  <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
  <h5 class="modal-title">
    <a href='https://www.google.com/' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer noopener nofollow'>WHY IS THIS LINK NOT OPENING?</a>
    <h5>
</aside>
```

Comment: can you provide the full code? What is .card in your html? Also courseCard is not defined anywhere, probably best to create a sandbox or codepen, then I would be happy to look.

Comment: I added the code for the card but the modal opens fine. issue is that the href link in the modal does not work.

Comment: Sure, but how am I supposed to debug it if I can't see the actual modal? courseCard is still not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Issue is not with the JS code to open the modal but that the links IN the modal do not work.  This must be some kind of default behaviour and I think I will try and bodge it in JS to handle the links rather than letting the html do it.

Comment: One issue you have is every time you click on a card you are adding more and more event handlers to the elements.

Comment: I made it run. The links are clickable in the demo, it is not opening them up in the demo since it is blocked in the iframe of the test window. You did not provide the HTML of the overlay.

Comment: Ok but adding more event handlers to the elements would not stop the href's from working in the modal?

Comment: I can not reproduce it in the example above. The links work but are blocked by the sandbox.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either. I am going for the JS bodge to handle the hrefs in JS rather than the html. This is not an in production project so it does not need to be perfect, it just needs to work.

Comment: the overlay is an empty div with the class of overlay! I have also checked this to make sure it is not a z-index issue of the overlay being on-top of the modal.

Comment: So we can agree the posted problem "Why is this link not opening" is not reproducible? The link opens Google for  me, and apparently for the OP and @epascarello . There are issues the modal doesn't close using posted code but that is not being questioned.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. issue has been found and fixed.

I was using scrollIntoView to handle page nav and smooth scrolling and I imprecisely targeted all "a" elements before I wrote the code for this current section with "a" elements inside of modal containers. Solved issue by giving the page nav a's an additional class then targeting that class only for that section of JS code! Doooooh.